# Query with dynamic schema without using string concatenation

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a system that uses a Oracle database, with a schema that is different from the application user. The schema name itself is not known in advance, so we can't just hardcode it. It's a system property.

Most of the data access is through Hibernate, which can specify the default schema on connection so this is not a problem in those cases.

However, there are a few places where plain SQL queries are used (using spring jdbcTemplate). So right now we have something that boils down to:

```
Map<String,Object> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT A, B, C FROM "+schema+".TABLE WHERE blablablah");
```

And this, of course, is an open SQL injection vulnerability. We're planning security audits and this will be flagged for sure.

So the question is: How do I specify the schema on the query, be it with jdbcTemplate, another Sprint data access utility, or even plain jdbc?

Thank you,
JGN

Comment: Do you really want to specify it for each statement - do you access objects from multiple schemas? Or could you [`set current_schema`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20531823/266304) as each session is created, either in your code of via [a login trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30127939/266304) that recognises your application user?

Comment: You could create Oracle synonyms for the database objects you reference. Then you wouldn't need to specify a schema in your SQL at all.

Comment: The problem is that the schema name is not known at coding time - hence, we'd have to use something like:
`update("ALTER SESSION SET_CURRENT_SCHEMA=?", schemaNameFromAppProperties);`
which I think doesn't work with Oracle, or something like this:
`update("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=" + schemaNameFromAppProperties)` which will get flagged again as SQL injection vulnerability in the scan.

Comment: The latter isn't really a problem for SQL injection though, as you'd control where the schema value comes from, e.g. a property file.  Unless someone malicious can modify that, in which case you probably have bigger problems. A login trigger would hide it from your application completely, but you may prefer the control.

Comment: I know I control it, but the folks that control the static scan are not the most open to reason ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Connection.setSchema` to specify the schema for a JDBC connection. This should be done before you create the Statement to execute a SQL command.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it covers the "even using plain jdbc" request. I'll try to propagate it into the jdbcTemplate (maybe by overloading the DataSource.getConnection method, I'm already using a custom DataSource), but at worst I can use plain JDBC with this suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: One caveat to this answer - `Connection.setSchema(schema)` was added on Java 1.7 - therefore, not all drivers will support it (for example, Oracle supports it only from version 12 of the drivers as far as I could find), and you will get weird NoSuchMethod errors at runtime.